# Acumatica event handle refresh page on time

Tags: acumatica

I've added more 3 field on Cases (ScreenId=CR306000)
1. UsrHours
2. UsrMinutes
3. UsrSeconds
This is my Code Editor: CRCaseMaint (Cases):

```
private static int i;
private static int j;
private static int k;
public PXAction<PX.Objects.CR.CRCase> ButtonStart;
[PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.Process)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start")]
protected void buttonStart()
{            
  var row1 = (CRCase)Base.Case.Current;
  CRCaseExt rowExt1 = PXCache<CRCase>.GetExtension<CRCaseExt>(row1);  

  i++;
  if(i > 59){
    i=0;
    rowExt1.UsrSeconds = "00";
    j++;
    if(j > 59){
      j=0;
      rowExt1.UsrMinutes = "00";
      k++;
      if(k > 59){
        k=0;
        rowExt1.UsrHours = "00";
      }
      else
      if(k < 10){
        rowExt1.UsrHours = "0" + k;
      }
      else{
        rowExt1.UsrHours = k.ToString();
      }
    }
    else
    if(j < 10){
      rowExt1.UsrMinutes = "0" + j;
    }
    else{
      rowExt1.UsrMinutes = j.ToString();
    }
  }
  else 
  if(i < 10){
    rowExt1.UsrSeconds = "0" + i;
  } 
  else{
    rowExt1.UsrSeconds = i.ToString();
  } 

}
```

As below picture:
[image]

right now I'm using (1) button and when I click it, it'll increase one by one. But I do want to know how can I write with (2) button? Do I need write it with JavaScript and add action button? If I want to update on load (refresh page on time), what event handle of Acumatica that I can use?

[image]

Comment: you mean, you need to add a button hiding the one on datasource? if yes check the answer below.

Comment: The answer that you write below as the point "Add a button manually to the datasource", is it in my picture (3) above my question?

Answer (score 0):

First hide the button which is shown by acumatica on the datasource.
For this,

- go to your customization project [Acumatica]
- Add the screen there
- open the screen and go to datasource
- Add a button manually to the datasource
- se the properties [Name = ButtonStart, Visible = False]

Now you manually add a new button to the correct position in your screen and set the properties [target = ds(datasource name), command = ButtonStart]

So now your new button will trigger your same action written in the graph.